# DDNS not setting my IP correctly

Tags: ddns

I am trying to configure the DDNS in my router (a NuCom 11N model). I'm using no-ip.com DDNS. When the IP gets updated, it is set to `192.168.1.2` instead of my public IP.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: My guess is that your modem is performing NAT and assigning a private IP to your router which is preventing your router from knowing its external IP address.

Comment: Mmm, and how should I solve that?

Comment: If that is indeed the case, which it may not be, you'll need to get to your modem's configuration page and set it to bridge mode instead of NAT mode. This will assign the external IP directly to the device attached to the modem (the router). Specifically how to do this varies between manufacturers and models.